# Switching leaflet image overlay layers shows white blinks

Tags: leaflet, javascript, mapbox, jquery

I am switching between image overlay layers upon user entry (through a slider).

Every time users get into this loop, a fast blink (with white background) is displaying, meaning that the old layer is removed before the new one finished rendering. I was relying on the "load" event, but it seems not affordable. It looks like the "load" event (fired by the added overlay image) is fired before the load completes.

```
mymap.addLayer(overlay[newlyr]);
overlay[newlyr].once("load",function() { 
    mymap.removeLayer(overlay[oldlyr]); 
    });
```

In other applications I have verified that the "load" event is very reliable for tile Layers, but it isn't at all for Image Overlays.
I hope I am doing something wrong.

Any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not get any blinking.

https://plnkr.co/edit/nIdNwTpDjZNhyiCzGJPC?p=preview

```js
var current = L.imageOverlay(url1, bounds).addTo(map);
var next = L.imageOverlay(url2, bounds);

setTimeout(swapImgs, 1000); // Just to swap without user action.

function swapImgs() {
  console.log('swap! ' + new Date());
  // Workaround for the fact that "load" event fires only the very first time,
  // when the browser has fetched the image from network.
  // After that, the browser serves from its cache and does not fire "load".
  // But the <img> element now has the `complete` property true.
  if (next.getElement() && next.getElement().complete) {
    map.addLayer(next);
    removeCurrent();
  } else {
    next.once('load', function() {
      removeCurrent();
    });
    map.addLayer(next);
  }
}

function removeCurrent() {
  map.removeLayer(current);

  // Just to implement the swapping.
  var swap = current;
  current = next;
  next = swap;
  setTimeout(swapImgs, 1000);
}
```

Comment: yes. Maybe my user is moving the slider too fast...
With a 1 sec timeout it is ok.

Comment: Looking at your code, I think that the part within `if (next.loaded)` is never executed... When you ask to swap, next image is not yet loaded. What that check is for?

Comment: You can decrease the delay between swaps. Even at 100ms I still do not get white blinking? (well, kinda hard to see as the map is blinking between 2 images…)

Comment: As for the `loaded` property trick, it is a workaround for the fact that `"load"` event fires only after the browser fetches the image from the network. Once it is in cache, it no longer fires the event. You could instead check the `complete` property. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached or http://mikefowler.me/journal/2014/04/22/cached-images-load-event for example.

Comment: I have edited the above code and live example to use the standard `complete` property on the `<img>` element, instead of the custom `loaded` property.

Comment: Thank you! I have checked the behavior is different from CHrome Android or iOS Safari. On iOS it still blinks... I'm going to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar problem. When I drag map and then drop it - imageOverlay starts loading only when I add it to map.
I ended up with such code (I force loading image before adding it to map):

```
    let imageLayer = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds)

    imageLayer._initImage()

    imageLayer.once('load', () => {
        that.map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
           that.map.removeLayer(layer);
        });

        imageLayer.addTo(that.map)
     });
```